# Rewrite query with only 1 group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

This bellow query will result the post wise sum of like

```
SELECT
      tblPost.Post,
      SUM(tblPost.LikeCount),
      CASE WHEN tblPost.Time 
           BETWEEN (SELECT 
                          CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
                          DATEADD(DD,DATEDIFF(DD 0,GETDATE()),-60),120)) AND CONVERT(date,GETUTCDATE()) 
           THEN 'Last 60 Days'
           ELSE 'More Than 1 Year'
      END AS"date type"
FROM tblPost 
INNER JOIN tblProfile ON (tblProfile.ID=tblPost.UID)
INNER JOIN tblWatchList ON (tblWatchList.ID=tblProfile.UID)
WHERE dbo.tblPost.Time BETWEEN (SELECT 
                                     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
                                     DATEADD(DD,DATEDIFF(DD,0,GETDATE()), -60),120))AND CONVERT(date,GETUTCDATE()) 
GROUP BY tblPost.Post,tblPost.Time
```

This is my query and it is working fine but I want to rewrite this. How can I describe it here... in my query I am having two `GROUP BY` clauses (`tblPost.Post`,`tblPost.Time`) and exactly here I'm getting a problem. I want to rewrite this query such as a way that I can group my result only by `tblPost.Post`

Please help me.

Comment: remove the group by tblpost.time part? or do you still want to get the same results, if you give us some sample data, table definitions and expected result we will be able to help much better

Comment: you need to tell us what you're hoping to achieve, not some vaguery about altering the `group by` clause

Comment: This is my data

post like date
xyz 5 today
abc 1 today
abc 3 today
stu 7 yesterday
oop 3 yesterday
abc 1 yesterday
abc 0 day before yesterday
stu 4 yesterday
oop 6 day before yesterday
xyz 7 day before yesterday
xyz 6 day before yesterday

this is im expecting 

post like date
xyz 1 today
abc 4 today
stu 11 yesterday
oop 3 yesterday
abc 1 yesterday
abc 0 day before yesterday
oop 6 day before yesterday
xyz 13 day before yesterday

Comment: the exact problem is.... i am accessing 3 column in select region and 1 of them is with aggregate function so i am bound to use 2 out of those three column (except that aggregate one) to group by my result. now my question is can i use only 1 of those column ?

Comment: Indrajit, this is your opportunity to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE clause already eliminates the two options you've presented for tblPost.Time - you explicitly state you're only ever going to retrieve "Last 60 days" so why are you bothering to have a whole CASE statement in the query?

And you're joining tables that aren't even represented. So start by cleaning your query up, use some aliases, and drop what you don't need:

```
SELECT P.Post, SUM(P.LikeCount)
FROM dbo.tblPost P
WHERE P.Time BETWEEN (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DD,DATEDIFF(DD,0,GETDATE()), -60),120)) AND CONVERT(date, GETUTCDATE()) 
GROUP BY P.Post
```